# Для движка интернет-магазина: InnoDB или MyISAM?

Tags: php, mysql

Для движка интернет-магазина (php) какой тип таблиц лучше делать: InnoDB или MyISAM ?

В чем отличия этих типов?

Чем можете обосновать свой выбор?

Answer (score 2):

Если возникает такой вопрос, лучше взять MyIsam: больше терпимость к глюкам и неаккуратному обращению.
InnoDB позволяет нормально лочить таблицы, работает чуть быстрее. Но в случае поломки таблицы без бэкапа восстановить почти нереально.

Comment: т.е. делать бэкап и innodb ? :)

Comment: Да. Но тут тоже есть тонкости: если база нормализована плохо, а обновляется часто, бэкап надо делать тоже очень часто. Хотя это не проблема Инны, это проблема выбора движка.

Answer (score 2):

Магазин? Только InnoDB, потому что вам наверняка понадобятся транзакции.

Только настройте сервер правильно, чтобы "терпимость к глюкам и неаккуратному обращению" вам не пригодилась.

А лучше - возьмите тот же postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего разницу не почувствуете.

[InnoDB vs MyISAM](http://fstrange.ru/coder/mysql/innodb-vs-myisam.html)

Статью писал давно, но принципиально ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

*InnoDB*. Потому, что есть 2 больших преимущества:

- не блокирует всю таблицу а только одну строку (MyISAM блокирует всю таблицу)
- можно построить связи